# Lookup function not returning value

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a dataset in SSRS that uses the following TSQL for the dataset:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Judge.EventJudgeID ) AS Row ,
    Judge.EventJudgeID ,
    Judge.EventID ,
    Judge.Judge_PersonID ,
    Judge.Passcode ,
    Persons.LastName + ' ' + Persons.FirstName AS JudgeName ,
    Events.EventName ,
    Events.EventDate
FROM    DB.dbo.tblEventJudge Judge
    INNER JOIN DB.dbo.Persons Persons ON PersonID = Judge_PersonID
    INNER JOIN DB.dbo.tblEvents Events ON Events.EventID = Judge.EventID
```

For a given event it will return the following data:

[image]

I have an SSRS report that I want to put the Judge's names on that looks like this:
[image]

In the expression for Judge 1 I have the following:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Row.Value,1,Fields!JudgeName.Value,"UpperRightBox")
```

and this appears to function just fine.  So I put the following in Judge 2 box:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Row.Value,2,Fields!JudgeName.Value,"UpperRightBox")
```

This returns a blank with no information in it.  I do not fully understand why it isn't looking up Row 2 and populating it with the JudgeName value.  I am using SQL Server 2012, but that shouldn't matter because the report isn't deployed yet.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to swap the first two arguments. The syntax is:

```
Lookup(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)
```

> **source_expression**: Evaluates the source expression in the current scope.
>
> **destination_expression**: Evaluates the destination expression for each row of the specified dataset after filters have been applied,
>   based on the collation of the specified dataset.

So for the second field you need to say: take this constant number: 2 (source), and go through all the rows in the dataset "UpperRightBox", and when you find a row with a 2 in the column called "Row" (destination), tell me what the Judge name was in that row (result).